# Deleted copy constructor of tuple member cause error

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-constructor, stdtuple

This piece of code

```
#include <tuple>

struct Foo
{
    Foo(const int& value):value_(value){}

    //Foo(const Foo&)=delete; // delete copy constructor

    int value_;
};

int main()
{
    std::tuple<Foo> tup(std::move(Foo(1)));
    return 0;
}
```

works fine but if you delete the `Foo` copy constructor it fails with the following compile error: use of deleted function `Foo::Foo(const Foo&)`.

But, since I am telling explicitly that the object can be moved, why the `std::tuple` constructor uses the `Foo` copy constructor instead of its moving constructor? How can I enforce the `std::tuple` to be constructed moving the `Foo` instance instead of copying it?

Comment: Declaring the copy-constructore (as deleted or not) inhibits the generation of the move-constructor. Then, only the copy constructor is viable for taking in a `Foo&&`, and it is deleted.

Comment: So I can simply fix it adding the following moving constructor `Foo(const Foo&& foo){value_=foo.value_;}`. Am I right? In this way Foo can me moved and not copyed.

Comment: @MarcoAgnese, no, that is not right. Move constructors that take `const` arguments are useless. See my answer.

Comment: You don't have to call `std::move` with an argument that is already an rvalue

Comment: @JonathanWakely I did a copy and paste and I forgot to remove the const qualifier :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But, since I am telling explicitly that the object can be moved,

No, you are telling the compiler that you *want* the object to be moved. That's not the same thing.

> why the `std::tuple` constructor uses the `Foo` copy constructor instead of its moving constructor?

Because when you delete the copy constructor the implicit move constructor does not exist, so it can't be used.

> How can I enforce the std::tuple to be constructed moving the Foo instance instead of copying it?

Either don't delete the copy constructor, or define a move constructor as well:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(const int& value):value_(value){}

    Foo(const Foo&)=delete; // delete copy constructor

    Foo(Foo&&)=default;

    int value_;
};
```

N.B. the `std::move` here is completely useless:

```
std::tuple<Foo> tup(std::move(Foo(1)));
```

All `std::move` does is cast its argument to an rvalue, but the temporary `Foo(1)` is already an rvalue, so you are casting an rvalue to an rvalue: useless. Furthermore, without the `std::move` the compiler can do [copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) and optimise away the actual move, but when you use `std::move` it can't do that and you make the code *slower* not faster!

The optimum code is the simplest version:

```
std::tuple<Foo> tup(Foo(1));
```

Or even simpler:

```
std::tuple<Foo> tup(1);
```

Comment: why the superfluous casting inhibit copy elision?

Comment: Because you're no longer just constructing `tup` from `Foo(1)`, you're constructing `tup` from the result of some function which is passed `Foo(1)` as an argument. The rules for copy elision only allow it in specific cases, and that is not one of them.